# How to call parameterized constructor controller action in another controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, object, service, constructor

I am having two controller. 1st controller having parameterized constructor and some methods. Now I have to call that methods in my another controller. is there any way to do it?

Below is code

```
public partial class oneController : Controller
{
   private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;
   public oneController(IEmployeeService employeeService)
   {
      this._employeeService = employeeService;
   }

   // some methods


}

public partial class twoController : Controller
{
  // Need to call some methods from oneController
}
```

Comment: Both are in same file or separate files?

Comment: Both controller having separate files..

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("youactionname","twoController", new{ your parameters })` ..

Comment: Dear mmushtaq, I don't redirect.. I just want to call method with param and get return value in 2nd controller action.. Means I don't want to repeat method that I already created in 1st  controller.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870413/how-to-call-another-controller-action-from-a-controller-in-mvc this can be your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as follow:

```
public partial class twoController : Controller{
     oneController  one = new oneController();
     one.AnyMethod(AnyParam);
}
```

But you're trying to do something the controllers aren't designed for. if you have some common method which is being accessible from multiple `controllers` then create required method as an public method in some class and invoke from any controller/actions you want.