# want to call controller method from class and get controller context without making request to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to call a controller method from a class and get the controller context without making requests to the controller. What are possible ways of doing that?

I can call method by creating an object of a controller class but I am unable to get controller's context.

```
var controllerObj = new HomeController()
controllerObj.methodA();
```

and in `methodA` request context is not available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the instance of a `Controller` in a class using [DependencyResolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dependencyresolver(v=vs.118).aspx).

```
public class Example
{    
    public static void CallActionMethod()
    {
        var controller = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<AboutController>();
        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(System.Web.HttpContext.Current
        .Request.RequestContext, controller);    
        controller.Index();    
    }  
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32098348/2218697)

Comment: I already have done like that,but as your answer is correct so I am marking it correct.