# Calling one Controller's action from another in mvc core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

The question "[How to call another controller Action From a controller in Mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870413/how-to-call-another-controller-action-from-a-controller-in-mvc)"
has some good answers, but it would seem things have changed. The answer

```
var controller = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ControllerB>();
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(this.Request.RequestContext, controller);
```

doesn't work in mvc core because `DependencyResolver` and a 2 param `ControllerContext` constructor no longer exist.

What is the new way to do this?

I don't want to redirect. I don't want to loose the controller context.

Comment: Looks like I can inject `controller2` into `controller1`'s constructor by adding `AddControllersAsServices` to the startup. I can also pass it in using `[FromServices]` on the individual endpoint. I don't know if that gives me an isolated controller, though. Also, I still don't know how to set it's context...

Answer (score 0):

I got my application working - so far - with this trick:

var useController = new ControllerB();
 useController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(this.ControllerContext);

As you see - much simpler, and at least AUTH worked.