# call razor page from mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to reuse my razor pages instead of having multiple similar views in mvc, I don't want to use a partial view. Thus I want to pass a parameter from a controller to razor page.

In the razor page my input will be something like below

```
public async Task OnGet(int? x,int?y)
```

How can i call this function/razor page from my mvc controller?

Comment: Is OnGet api from another controller ?

Comment: Return RedirectToAction()

Answer (score 3):

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
 {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {           
            return RedirectToPage("/index", new { name = "Arun Kumar"});
        }
 }
```

Razor Page:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
 {
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public void OnGet(string name)
        {
            FullName = name;
            ViewData["heading"] = "Welcome  to ASP.NET Core Razor Pages !!";

        }
 }
```

Razor Page View:

```
@page
@model RazorMVCMix.Pages.IndexModel



<h1>@ViewData["heading"]</h1>

<h2>@Model.FullName</h2>
```

Output here:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are just classes you can call action like methods from another controller.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264392/is-a-good-practice-to-call-a-controller-function-from-another-controller

[How to call another controller Action From a controller in Mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870413/how-to-call-another-controller-action-from-a-controller-in-mvc)

https://forums.asp.net/t/1645726.aspx?how+to+call+a+controller+action+from+another+controller

Comment: How do i return a razor page with parameters from an mvc controller? What is the syntax

Comment: The razor page you want to return must be from some controller action . Call that action using new Controller.Action(params) return result as result is IActionResult for mvc. You dont need to cal View() method just return result.

Comment: Razor pages don’t have a controller

Comment: If you dont want partial view return that razor from another controller action call that action from your controller there you can pass down view model as param. Or use custom HtmlHelper instead of razor view.

Comment: Appreciate your effort but doesn’t answer my question of returning/calling razor page method with param from mvc controller output

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action, use [RedirectToPageResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.redirecttopageresult.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_RedirectToPageResult__ctor_System_String_System_Object_):

```
return new RedirectToPageResult("/YourRazorPage", new {x = 1, y = 2});
```

Comment: thanks the only problem is my controller which is located in "~/Areas/Base/Controllers/HomeController.cs"   and my razor pages are in  "~/Pages/Objects/".   When using "return RedirectToPageResult("/YourRazorPage".... it isattempting look within "~/Areas/Base". The only method which doesn't use relative referencing is "Redirect("/Obejcts") but i cannot pass parameters with this method.